# Type hinting in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, type-hinting, python-typing

In [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), type hinting was added to Python 3 with the inclusion of the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module. Is there any way to do this in Python 2? All I can think of is having a decorator to add to methods to check types, but this would fail at runtime and not be caught earlier like the hinting would allow.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

According to [**Suggested syntax for Python 2.7 and straddling code**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code) in PEP 484 which defined type hinting, there is an alternative syntax for compatibility with Python 2.7. It is however not mandatory so I don't know how well supported it is, but quoting the PEP:

> Some tools may want to support type annotations in code that must be compatible with Python 2.7. For this purpose this PEP has a suggested (but not mandatory) extension where function annotations are placed in a # type: comment. Such a comment must be placed immediately following the function header (before the docstring). An example: the following Python 3 code:
>
> ```
> def embezzle(self, account: str, funds: int = 1000000, *fake_receipts: str) -> None:
>     """Embezzle funds from account using fake receipts."""
>     <code goes here>
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> def embezzle(self, account, funds=1000000, *fake_receipts):
>     # type: (str, int, *str) -> None
>     """Embezzle funds from account using fake receipts."""
>     <code goes here>
> ```

For `mypy` support, see [**Type checking Python 2 code**](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/4687cec37a2a28e477e0fcf7eb95d2701bea55eb/docs/source/python2.rst).

Comment: Hmm ok, should have read the docs further. Do you know if there any tools that currently support this? Not sure if it is just a standard or if there is actual tooling implemented yet.

Comment: According to PyCharm "PyCharm supports type hinting in function annotations and type comments using the typing module defined by PEP 484." The reference to TYPE COMMENTS makes it clear that it should be supported. I don't use pyCharm on this computer so I cannot check it right now.

EDIT : link to pycharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html#d316912e110

Comment: Thanks, also found that Emacs Jedi works with it as well.

Comment: A bit off-topic: perhaps you know how could I extract this type annotation in Python 2? It's not included in `__doc__` attr and `__annotations__` attr is not available in Python 2.

Comment: I am not aware of any automatic tool to do that, but given the PEP they should always be in the first line right after the function  declaration and start with # type: so that should be quite easy to get with inspect.getsourcelines (https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines), and then parsed.

Comment: @CzarekTomczak Currently, there's a module available that parses Python with type comments (and it seems to support Python 2.7) called [typed-ast](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typed-ast/). I'm using it only for Python 3.5 though.

Comment: @mbdevpl Looks like this package can parse Python 2.7 type comments, but it requires Python 3 to run it. Nevertheless useful, thanks.

Comment: @Andrew: Are you saying that you got PEP-0484 type annotation working in Emacs Jedi with Python *2* ? Doesn't work here. It's advertized as supported for Python *3* only AFAIU (see: "[function annotations (python 3 only; python 2 function annotations with comments in planned but not yet implemented)](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/blob/be2a97cd36ce1b7d6f587ef122efc3433b1e8ae2/docs/docs/features.rst#type-hinting)")

Comment: Will this work on earlier versions of Python 3 as well?

Comment: Thanks. It works in VS Code (1.63.1).

Answer (score 17):

At this point the recommended and python3 compatible way to do is to follow the python2 to 3 guide : http://python-future.org/func_annotations.html

```
def embezzle(self, account: str, funds: int = 1000000, *fake_receipts: str) -> None:
    """Embezzle funds from account using fake receipts."""
    pass
```

Become:

```
def embezzle(self, account, funds = 1000000, *fake_receipts):
    """Embezzle funds from account using fake receipts."""
    pass
embezzle.__annotations__ = {'account': str, 'funds': int, 'fake_receipts': str, 'return': None}
```

Comment: this will not work for non-literal types like `List`, `Set`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function i wrote to parse the Python 2 type comment and get a tuple of input types and the return type. It would need some work to work with complex type definitions from the typing library (Any, Optional, List, etc.):

```
class InvalidTypeHint(Exception):
    pass    

PYTHON_2_TYPE_HINT_REGEX = "\s*#\s*type:\s*(\(.+\))\s*->\s*(.+)\s*"

def parse_python_2_type_hint(typehint_string):
    # type: (str) -> (tuple, type)
    pattern = re.compile(PYTHON_2_TYPE_HINT_REGEX)
    search_results = pattern.search(typehint_string)
    if not search_results:
        raise InvalidTypeHint('%s does not match type hint spec regex %s' % (typehint_string, PYTHON_2_TYPE_HINT_REGEX))
    arg_types_str = search_results.group(1)
    return_type_str = search_results.group(2)
    try:
        arg_types_tuple = eval(arg_types_str)
        assert isinstance(arg_types_tuple, tuple)
        return_type = eval(return_type_str)
        assert isinstance(return_type, type)
    except Exception as e:
        raise InvalidTypeHint(e)
    return arg_types_tuple, return_type


def parse_arg_types_for_callable(func):
    # type:(callable)->tuple
    """

    :param func:
    :return: list of parameter types if successfully parsed, else None
    """

    # todo make this compatible with python 3 type hints
    # python 2.7 type hint
    source_lines = inspect.getsource(func).split("\n")
    def_statements = 0
    for source_line in source_lines:
        try:
            arg_types_tuple, return_type = parse_python_2_type_hint(source_line)
            return arg_types_tuple
        except InvalidTypeHint:
            if source_line.strip().startswith("def "):
                def_statements += 1
            if def_statements > 1:
                return None
```