# Using typing module in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

The typing module is a back port for earlier version of Python to infer input and output datatypes.  I am having an issue getting it to work in Python 2.7.

```
import typing
def greeting(name): # type: (str) -> str
    """documentations"""
    return ('Hello ' + name)
print(greeting.__annotations__) # fails because doesn't exist.
```

I've also tried this:

```
import typing
def greeting(name # type: str
             ):
    # type: (...) -> str
    """documentations"""
    return ('Hello ' + name)
```

And this:

```
import typing

def greeting(name):
    # type: (str) -> str
    """documentations"""
    return ('Hello ' + name)
```

This should create an `__annotations__` property on the class according to PEP484, but I do not see this happening at all.

What am I doing wrong with the backport code?

Comment: Possibly see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230635/type-hinting-in-python-2

Comment: @khelwood this does not work, so if I do what I did above with the type notation it doesn't work.  The ```__annotations__``` never gets population in the 3.5 version or 2.7

Comment: Have you tried putting the type annotation comment on its own line?

Comment: @zondo i added additional information above.

Comment: Are you running your code with something like `mypy --py2 program.py`?  If you're running with normal Python, nothing is interpreting the type annotations.

Comment: @zondo ok, so you need to run mypy to use this, not the normal python.exe.  Should this notation work with python 3.5 and 3.6?

Comment: Where did this backport come from? How are we supposed to help you with code not in your question? What's "mypy"?

Comment: You would still need to run it with mypy.  Python 3 introduces type annotations in normal syntax, but the comment stuff needs to be interpreted by mypy.

Comment: Note that there are other type annotation interpreters.  You don't have to use mypy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typing` is a module that was introduced in Python 3.5 . The examples in PEP 484 rely on a Python 3+, and `__annotations__` is a Python 3 concept. The backport can only allow to use the types of functions defined in the `typing` module, but it does not change the Python engine to magically understand all Python 3 concepts.

A discussion in that other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35230792) suggests that the annotations should be accessible by using `inspect.getsourcelines` to research the first line right after the function declaration and starting with # type. A [`typed-ast`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typed-ast/) module exists on pypi and should be able to parse Python 2.7 style annotations. Unfortunately it is only declared at beta level and only compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Should Python 3.5 understand the ```# type``` notation then?

Comment: Am I wrong that mypy can interpret them in both Python 2 and 3?