# How can I use Function Annotation in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, annotations, ipython

I saw this source code in Ipython:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/e1e2e960315f0f98703f6b8b077b10c99d04d70a/IPython/core/completer.py#L314

I know it is a new feature called `Function Annotation` in python3.

but this code may also work in Python 2.7. Why?

How can I use `Function Annotation` in Python 2.7?

Comment: Even in PY3 the use of annotations is limited.  The interpreter does not use them.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230635/type-hinting-in-python-2

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the new (3.5+) annotation syntax directly in 2.7, but if you have python 3.4+ you can install mypy and run it on your 2.7 code with a different syntax. See [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code).

The example you pointed to in your link could be written in 2.7 as:

```
class Completion:
    def __init__(self, start, end, text, type=None, _origin=''):
        # type: (int, int, str, str, str) -> None
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use function annotations in Python 2.7.  That said, the main use of function annotations is for gradual typing, which can be done with comments in Python 2.7.

Comment: hi can you sight an example for Python 2.7 please.