# How to make Jupyter Notebook look in the right place for a module?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04

Using a Jupyter Notebook running with the python2 kernel, I tried to import `emcee` and I got an error message:

```
File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/emcee/ensemble.py", line 84
    parameter_names: Optional[Union[Dict[str, int], List[str]]] = None,
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

apparently because I am using the python2 kernel.

I then installed ipykernal using: `python3 -m pip install ipykernel`

I then opened a Jupyter Notebook using the Python3 kernel. I again tried to `import emcee` but I had the same problem. It was still looking for the `emcee` module in the python2 path.

I then did `pip3 install emcee`, opened a Jupyter Notebook (python3 kernel) but I still have the same issue.

I think I need to tell Jupyter Notebook to look for the python3 version of emcee, but I'm not sure how to. I just tried:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/'
```

But again, this didn't fix it. I checked the `sys.path` in my Jupyter Notebook and the new python path didn't seem to be added.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: You have `python3` in your pc, right?

Comment: Yes I do have python 3 installed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jupyter Notebook wasn't really using the python3 kernel even though it said it was:

My python3 kernel was located: `/home/damejia/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`

The `kernel.json` file was:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

But "python" just points to my python2. I changed "python" to "python3" and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here the issue is not from your side, this issue is mainly from there side. They,there refers to `emcee`.
**Explination:**
They are basically using `annotation` [here](https://github.com/dfm/emcee/blob/main/src/emcee/ensemble.py#L84) where you are getting error, and you are using `python2` to import this library, which don't support `annotation`.

Here's a bit of information about annotation(Some of the stackoverflow question).

- [What are variable annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations)

> `primes: List[int] = []` and `stats: Dict[str, int] = {}`. Everything between `:` and the `=` is a type hint, so `primes` is indeed defined as `List[int]`, and initially set to an empty list (and `stats` is an empty dictionary initially, defined as `Dict[str, int]`).

- [Function parameter with colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962869/function-parameter-with-colon)

> It's a function annotation; function arguments and the return value can be tagged with arbitrary Python expressions. Python itself ignores the annotation (other than saving it), but third-party tools can make use of them.

- [How can I use function annotation in python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060055/how-can-i-use-function-annotation-in-python-2-7)

> You can't use the new (3.5+) annotation syntax directly in 2.7, but if you have python 3.4+ you can install mypy and run it on your 2.7 code with a different syntax. See [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code).

Now if jupyter notebook is not using python3 then the solution is [create virtual environment](https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/) and try running there. You may add your issue in [new issue](https://github.com/dfm/emcee/issues/new/choose) they will help but if you know what you are doing then you may change that code too. If your edited code works for both python2 and 3 then you may [pull request](https://github.com/dfm/emcee/compare).