# What's the best way to hint types of return values in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

There are many ways in python to hint value type, like this:

```
def func(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a+b
```

But first, it will makes declaration looks complex. Seconds, it will cause some errors in a lower version of python.
I also used `:rtype:` and `:param value:` in docstrings to hint type, but it seems not a very popular way and not that beautiful.
I look into some open source library, but I didn't find out how they hint value type (or in some way I don't know).
So what's the most popular and beautiful way to hint value type? Better some way in docstring.

By the way, I'm using Vscode, and eager to know some way to help autocomplete know what's the type of value actually be returned by the function.

Comment: How would you determine whether something was popular? What are the metrics for beauty (other than [**`import this`**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))?

Comment: For me your example looks fine and not complex at all. Nevertheless, this question is *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: @Georgy The question specifically mentions incompatibility with earlier versions of Python (namely, Python 2.x).

Comment: @chepner You are right. I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

This is sort of a duplicated of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230635/type-hinting-in-python-2). Since you always want to use the official ways of type hinting, you should use the type comment for compatibility with the versions below python 3:

```
def func(a, b):
    # type: (int, int) -> int
    return a+b
```