# How to make Django, type annotations, and Flake8 work together?

Tags: django, types, django-rest-framework, python-3.7, flake8

I'm using Django / DRF. I want to write type-checked Python. I also want linting.

Django's model structure involves creating a manager class for every model, and assigning an instance of the manager class to the model's `objects` member.

Since I'm using type annotations, the manager class's methods now also includes a reference to the model. This causes flake8 to report an error in one or the other.

Here is an example:

```
class UserManager:

    def create_user(email: str) -> User:
        ...                        ^^^^ [flake8] F821: undefined name 'User'

class User:

    objects = UserManager()
```

And if I flip them around, I get:

```
class User:

    objects = UserManager()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^ [flake8] F821: undefined name 'UserManager'

class UserManager:

    def create_user(email: str) -> User:
        ...
```

What do people do to write typed, linted Django code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.7, you can fix this by using `from __future__ import annotations`, which will allow type annotations that contain forward references. This is preferred to using string annotations (as suggested by another answer) for simpler code refactoring and linting. Using quotes is simply a workaround for older versions of Python that don’t support forward-reference annotations. In Python 4 (if not sooner) this will be the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Note aside from typing:  Django's models **do not require** you to have an explicit Manager for every model! Django generates a Manager using the `objects` property on every model.  You only need to add a custom ModelManager for specific uses. Moving onto types...

I think you should put UserManager before User if you're actually using that class.  You can wrap the type in quotations for names that have not been defined yet, this is covered in the documentation for [PEP 484 under the "Forward References" section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references).

```
class UserManager:

    def create_user(email: str) -> "User":
        ...                        

class User:

    objects = UserManager()
```

The other option is to define type hints using Python 2 syntax in the comments, [Type hinting in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230635/type-hinting-in-python-2) shows a similar answer.

```
class UserManager:

    def create_user(email: str):
        # type: (str) -> User
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Out of curiosity, is there any documentation that says wrapping type hint classes in a string is also acceptable? This is the first time I'm hearing this.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references has a section called "Forward References" for type hints containing names that have not been defined yet.  I've added a reference to this in my answer.

Comment: If I have the managers in a diferent file and I try to import the `User` model raise the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'User' from partially initialized module 'my_app.users.models' (most likely due to a circular import)`. On the other hand if I use `User` model without import it mypy rainse error: `Name 'User' is not defined`.