# Typing for python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, strong-typing

Is there a way to do the following in python2.7:

```
class DailyPriceObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = None    #datetime.date
        self.sd_buy = None  # float
        self.hd_buy = None  # float
        self.sd_rent = None # float
        self.hd_rent = None # float
        self.revenue = None # float
```

I've used [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in later versions, but for a certain project the codebase is `2.7`.

Comment: Keep in mind, type annotations in Python are merely suggestions - the interpreter isn't going to hold anyone to adhere to the types that have been annotated.

That being said, the only support that Python 2 has for type annotations is through [specially formatted comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35230792/4739755)

Comment: Every version of Python is strongly typed. So, are you asking how to use type annotations in Python 2.7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230635/type-hinting-in-python-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation:

https://github.com/python/typing

> This GitHub repo is used for development of the typing module defined
>   by PEP 484. The module is available in Python since version 3.5.0 on a
>   provisional basis until Python 3.7.0.

So, no - you cannot use it with 2.7, sadly.

Comment: As @b_c says in the comments you can still you a type checker with python 2.7, you just need to include the annotations in comments (see [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python2.html))

Answer (score 1):

If you dear reader should ever stumble upon this post, you can nowadays declare type hints via comments like this to be picked up by the type checker of your IDE:

```
import datetime
class DailyPriceObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = None    # type: datetime.date
        self.sd_buy = None  # type: float
        self.hd_buy = None  # type: float
        self.sd_rent = None # type: float
        self.hd_rent = None # type: float
        self.revenue = None # type: float
```