# How resolve this issue? def _create_frequency_table(text_string)->dict: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, atom-editor

This is the part of the code:

```
'''
Don’t leave your dreams to chance.
'''


def _create_frequency_table(text_string) -> dict:
    """
    we create a dictionary for the word frequency table.
    For this, we should only use the words that are not part of the stopWords array.

    Removing stop words and making frequency table
    Stemmer - an algorithm to bring words to its root word.
    :rtype: dict
    """
    stopWords = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    words = word_tokenize(text_string)
    ps = PorterStemmer()
```

This is the part of code  I'm trying to understand..
and below is the error.

```
line 29
    def _create_frequency_table(text_string) -> dict:
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: type hints (i.e., the  `-> dict` part of you function definition there) were introduced in python 3.5, Python 2.7 won't understand them and give a syntax error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230635/type-hinting-in-python-2)

Comment: Guido van Rossum says python2 gonna die: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kn7NtlV6g0