# Type hint errors with VScode (python)

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

When I try writing type hint like so :

```
def test(a : int, b : int) -> int:
    y = a + b
    return y 

print(test(2,2))
```

I have the following error :

```
  File "/Users/vincentdescatoire/Documents/IUT/Algorythme/Révisions/DS1/Exercice1.py", line 2
    def test(a : int, b : int) -> int:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

of course, when I remove type hint, everything work :

```
def test(a, b):
    y = a + b
    return y 

print(test(2,2))
```

I'm assuming it's a VScode problem because everything work fine with PyCharm.
In terms of extension, I have : `Mypy, Python and PythonTypeHint` installed on VsCode.

Also, I'm on Mac (macOS Catalina)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version python are you using to run it?

Comment: hi, I'm using Python 2.7.16

Comment: But what version of python 3?

Comment: sorry, my bad; I'm on 2.7.16.
I'm currently updating

Comment: If you want to do type hinting without Python 3 try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230635/type-hinting-in-python-2

Comment: So, I finally fixed my problem and here is my solution : 
-> install python3 from python website
-> you can test your code from terminal using command :  `python3 nameofYourFile`

but now even if you click "run", vscode will still use python and not python3 
-> change your version on the bottom left of vscode


if it still don't work (my case) : 
-> go to  preferences > settings
-> type `code-runner.executorMap` in the search bar 
-> click `edit in settings.json`
-> search for the python line 
-> change it  to `"python": "python3",`

hope I was clear enough